# Django ListView get_queryset(self) breaks paginate_by

Tags: python, django, listview

In Django 1.6, I am using a ListView class. This works without paginate_by, but not with. I get `object of type 'NoneType' has no len()` when I use paginate_by. This is only after the first page, the first page has no issues. I'm not sure why  `def get_queryset(self)` is messing up `paginate_by` because all it's doing is defining the query_set.

```
class ViewLog(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "bot_data/log_view.html"
    model = Log
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        parameter = self.request.GET.get('search')
        user_alpha = self.request.GET.get('user_alpha')
        if parameter == "latest":
            return Log.most_recent.all()
        elif parameter == "oldest":
            return Log.least_recent.all()
        elif parameter == "ascending":
            return Log.user_aplha_ascend.all()
        elif parameter == "descending":
            return Log.user_aplha_descend.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        parameter = self.request.GET.get('search')
        context = super(ViewLog, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'current_url': parameter})
        return context
```

**EDIT**:
I found if I manually append search=ascending as ether `/log_view?search=ascending&page=2` or `/log_view?page=2&search=ascending` in the url window of the browser...both of these combos work. I guess at this point I need to found out how to do the pagination manually and to construct the URL's

Comment: Can you update your question with a full traceback and the `LoginRequiredMixin` class?